# discord.py how to make the bot not to kick the message author

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have a kick command

```
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def kick(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        
        await ctx.trigger_typing()
            
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{gem} **User kicked!**", color=colgreen)
        embed.add_field(name="**{} has been succesfully kicked from the server!**".format(member), value="**Reason: {}.**".format(reason), inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="{0}\nID: {1}\n{2}".format(ctx.message.author.name, ctx.message.author.id, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d %Y at %H:%M:%S %p")), icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

but if a user who has kick members permissions, and tries to kick himself, the bot will kick them.

how can i make the bot ignore the user and send a error that you cannot kick yourself??

ive tried if and else statetements, but its not working...
i will either get a error, or nothing...

Comment: *"I've tried if and else statements"*. Yeah, it does involve those. You might want to actually read about programming to write programs. You can also read those error messages, they are here to help you.

Comment: @spectras what you mean?

Comment: `if member == message.author: await ctx.send("You are attempting to kick yourself")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a if statement to check if the user is equal to the author, like this for example:

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def kick(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        if member == ctx.author: # Check if the user is the same as the author
            return

        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        
        await ctx.trigger_typing()
            
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{gem} **User kicked!**", color=colgreen)
        embed.add_field(name="**{} has been succesfully kicked from the server!**".format(member), value="**Reason: {}.**".format(reason), inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="{0}\nID: {1}\n{2}".format(ctx.message.author.name, ctx.message.author.id, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d %Y at %H:%M:%S %p")), icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: well, i was using similar if statements like this, but they were not working, but this one worked, weird. thanks man